# Curvature of Parallel Surface

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Problem from do Carmo. Given a regular parametrized surface $X(u,v)$ we define the parallel surface $Y(u,v)$ by $$Y(u,v)=X(u,v) + aN(u,v)$$ where $N(u,v)$ is the unit normal on $X$ and $a$ is a constant. Show that  $$Y_u\times Y_v=(1-2Ha+Ka^2)(X_u\times X_v).$$

My Ideia:

$$Y_u = X_u+aN_u \\ Y_v = X_v+aN_v$$

than
$$Y_u \times Y_v= (X_u+aN_u) \times (X_v+aN_v) = \\ (X_u \times Xv) + a(N_u \times X_v+X_u \times N_v)+a^2(N_u \times N_v)$$

Looking at where I want to go, I know I have to show that

$$N_u \times X_v+X_u \times N_v = 2H(X_u \times X_v) \\ N_u \times N_v = K(X_u \times X_v)$$

But I can't go on from there.

Comment: What if $X_u$ and $X_v$ are principal directions?

Comment: I'm thinking about your comment, but it's not helping me.

Comment: Work out that case for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is doing exactly what you've done, and then realized that $N_u$ and $N_v$ are in $T_pS$. For that reason, we can write as $N_u=-h^1_1X_u-h_1^2X_v$ and $N_v=-h^1_2X_u-h^2_2X_v$, where $h^i_j$ represents the local coefficient of the derivative of the norm:
$$(-dN)=\begin{bmatrix}h_1^1 & h_2^1\\ h_1^2 & h_2^2\end{bmatrix}$$
Knowing this, you can be back to the equation:
$$Y_u\times Y_v=X_u\times X_v+a(-h^1_1X_u-h_1^2X_v)\times X_v+X_u\times a(-h^1_2X_u-h^2_2X_v)+a^2(-h^1_1X_u-h_1^2X_v)\times (-h^1_2X_u-h^2_2X_v)$$
Because the cross product, then $X_u\times X_u=0=X_v\times X_v$, leading to the follow:
\begin{align*}Y_u\times Y_v&=X_u\times X_v+a(-h^1_1X_u)\times X_v+aX_u\times (-h^2_2X_v)+a^2[h^1_1h^1_2-(h^2_1)^2]\times X_v\\
&= X_u\times X_v [1-a(h^1_1+h^2_2)+a^2(h^1_1h^1_2-(h^2_1)^2)]\\
&= X_u\times X_v [1-2aH+a^2K^2)]
\end{align*}
Since, by definition, $H=trace(dN)$ and $K=det(dN)$.

Ps: Remembering that all that is evaluated at some point $p$.
Ps2: A tip for the following questions you can solve using this information or using that the normal vector is equal for both surfaces, which leads you to $Ã_{Y(u,v}(I-aA_{X(u,v)})=A_{X(u,v)}$ and then taking the determinant and the characteristic polynomial. This also solve this question in a more elegant way.